# how to use my base.html template in a view for another app in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a newsletter in my footer. My footer is stored in my `base.html` file, the problem is I need to render this template for a view in another app.

Here is my code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def new(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sub = Subscriber(email=request.POST['email'], conf_num=random_digits())
        sub.save()
        message = Mail(
            from_email=settings.FROM_EMAIL,
            to_emails=sub.email,
            subject='Newsletter Confirmation',
            html_content='Thank you for signing up for the StockBuckets email newsletter! \
                Please complete the process by \
                <a href="{}/confirm/?email={}&conf_num={}"> clicking here to \
                confirm your registration</a>.'.format(request.build_absolute_uri('/confirm/'),
                                                    sub.email,
                                                    sub.conf_num))
        sg = SendGridAPIClient(settings.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
        response = sg.send(message)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'email': sub.email, 'action': 'added', 'form': SubscriberForm()})
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': SubscriberForm()})
```

I want to replace both instance of `index.html` in the return statements from this view, to `base.html`. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: index page along with base? or only base?

Comment: @navaneethkrishnan. Pretty sure I only need the base.html template rendered in my view

Answer (score 1):

In Django all the templates files will be collected in single templates folder. so we have to create something like this.

```
Django_project/
    app_1/
        ..
    app_2/
        ..
    app_3/
        ..
    Django_project/
        settings.py
        manage.py
    templates/
        app_1/
            base.html
            other.html
        app_2/
            base.html
            other.html
        app_3/
            base.html
            other.html
        other_common.html
```

or use can add the templates inside the app itself,

```
Django_project/
    app_1/
        templates/
            app_1/
                base.html
                other.html
    app_2/
        templates/
            app_1/
                base.html
                other.html
```

Now if you want to use the base template from another app, you add `app_1/base.html` in your render function.